# signal.SIGINT in windows cause process exit directly

Tags: python, windows, signals

I wrote those test python code as following:

```
import signal
import time
import os

def handler(signum, frame):
    print "do whatever, like call thread.interrupt_main()"
    return

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

while 1:
    try:
        time.sleep(10)
    except:
        os.kill(int(os.getpid()), signal.SIGINT)
        pass
```

when i excute this test code on windows, the process print "do whatever, like call thread.interrupt_main()", then exit;
on linux, it works correctly.

why on windows it not work?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.kill

> Windows: The signal.CTRL_C_EVENT and signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT signals
>   are special signals which can only be sent to console processes which
>   share a common console window, e.g., some subprocesses. Any other
>   value for sig will cause the process to be unconditionally killed by
>   the TerminateProcess API, and the exit code will be set to sig.

Try following code:

```
import time

while 1:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "do whatever, like call thread.interrupt_main()"
```